# How to handle an object in the JSON object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following json `responseObject` array. I could able to get `orderid`, and `datetime` properties.

However, I wonder how I could able to handle the `products` objects in the json.

I would be grateful if you have any suggestion(s), feedback or recommendation(s)?

Here is the json **responseObject**

```
[
  {
    "orderid": "1",
    "datetime": "2017-07-29 23:31:53",
    "products": [
      {
        "productid": "2",
        "productname": "Beef Kabob",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderid": "2",
    "datetime": "2017-07-30 05:18:41",
    "products": [
      {
        "productid": "1",
        "productname": "Baked Chicken",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**ViewController.m** - Retrieve Data from the URL

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:AppConstant.getAllOrdersURL parameters:nil progress: nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull operation, id responseObject) 
{
    // retrieve and store them in the mutable array
    for ( id jsonItem in responseObject)
    {
       OrderData *orderItem = [[OrderData alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonItem];
       [self.orderElements addObject:orderItem];
    }
} 
failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

}];
```

**OrderData.m**

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)orderDict
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.datetime = [orderDict objectForKey:@"datetime"];
        self.orderid = [orderDict objectForKey:@"orderid"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Create a class for Product with a property productID and another one productName. Add a NSArray properties to your `OrderData` class to adds theses products to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OrderData you need add a productsArr property of type NSArray then in initWithDictionary:

```
self.productsArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[orderDict objectForKey:@"products"]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON may contain many `productid` and `productname` for single `orderDict` so iterate over the array product which contains a dictionary.

```
self.productArray = [NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[orderDict objectFOrKey@:@"products"]];
```